# How to loop through table and add form data to table dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I'm currently working on a sort of hour tracker website, and I am using a form and a table.

Right now I have it working where it adds the form content to the table the first time you submit, but I need it to allow you put in new information into the form and once submitted, it automatically adds a new row with the data.

So far I have this function:

```js
function enterText() {
  var i = 1;
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(i);

  if (document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML == "") {
    var x = document.getElementById("dt").value;
    document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = x;
  } else {
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    i++;
  }

  var y = document.getElementById("hrs").value;
  document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML = y;
  var z = document.getElementById("dsc").value;
  document.getElementById("td3").innerHTML = z;
}
```

So the end goal is to eventually not have to use a table either, but I am using it as a place holder.

edit*
to reply to Freek Bes: 
It does make sense to put i as a global. I tested it out a bit and just moving i doesn't make a difference from before, it just inputs the form into the first cell and then when submit is clicked again it adds a blank row. The second example just adds blanks cells. The problem is that I can't seem to get it to add the new content inside of the new cells. 
For better context of what I'm doing, here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="hours.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<header>Hour Tracker</header>
<p>Created by: </p>
<body onload= enterText();>
<form onsubmit="return false" id="first" class="hours">
    Date:<br>
    <input type="date" name="date" id="dt"><br>
    Hours:<br>
    <input type="number" name="hours" id="hrs"><br>
    Description:<br>
    <input type="text" name="description" id="dsc"><br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="enterText();">
</form>
<table id="myTable">
    <tr>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Hours</th>
        <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="td1"></td>
        <td id="td2"></td>
        <td id="td3"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you plan to do something with that data? Because you could add a lot of rows in that table, but once you click refresh, everything will go away, since it's not persistent.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to increment the variable i, but i is set to 1 again when you run the function a second time. You need the variable i to be global, by defining it outside of the function. Try this:

```
var i = 1;

function enterText() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(i);

  if (document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML == "") {
    var x = document.getElementById("dt").value;
    document.getElementById("td1").innerHTML = x;
  } else {
    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
    var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
    i++;
  }

  var y = document.getElementById("hrs").value;
  document.getElementById("td2").innerHTML = y;
  var z = document.getElementById("dsc").value;
  document.getElementById("td3").innerHTML = z;
}
```

This won't however set the data in the new row. In order for that to work, you'll have to get rid of the ids you're using for the cells alltogether (I don't know what you were trying to do in the if statement, so I got rid of it too for simplicity. You can add it back if you want and check the results yourself):

```
var i = 1;

function enterText() {
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var row = table.insertRow(i);

  var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);

  cell1.innerHTML = x;
  cell2.innerHTML = y;
  cell3.innerHTML = z;
  i++;
}
```